# Simple label edit using custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have done very simple programming here -     http://jsfiddle.net/micronyks/R7HEV/

Now what I want is, when I click button, I want my custom label to be converted into input field where user can input any value (at a same time same button should display 'save' text).

After writing new value in textbox when user clicks save button, I want my label to show new updated value just entered by user.

I don't know how can I do it. I need help.

Note: I want no other controls.

jsfiddle snippet:

my .js

```
var app=angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('startCtrl',function($scope){

    $scope.name = "Hello";
    $scope.click = function() {
        alert('button clicked');
    }

});


app.directive('myLabel',function(){
    return {
        restrict:"E",
        replace:true,
        template:'<div>{{name}}</div>'
    }
});
```

Comment: It's great that you've started something, but you haven't been able to do anything particular with your directive regarding the requirements you have. There's not much to do than code the entire thing for you, and that's not what SO is about. Would you mind showing a little more effort in completing this, and if you are unable to do anything more, ask a specific *why*, *"why does name not update from my directive"* for example, instead of "give me the code plz"

Comment: whoa!! Patrick I don't know how and from where to initiate? that's why, with incomplete fiddle, i've come here. I'm just stuck as i'm learning directives communication. But really not getting anything here.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/micronyks/R7HEV/2/

still have a look at here. It's not working but might give you some idea.

Comment: @Patrick. I think you gotta see this.  http://jsfiddle.net/micronyks/R7HEV/6/

Comment: Well done, you made it! If you'd like you can make an answer of it